# How to implement vault functionality in braintree to show existing card info to user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, braintree

I have integrated Braintree .net core API I am able to create a token using generate token method.
first time while passing client Id it is throwing an error.
Also, I have Request new customer during the TransactionRequest using CustomerRequest method where I passed userId, I also added StoreInVaultOnSuccess to true.
During the first transaction, I am able to create user but later it throws an error.
So could you please explain how to use vault  functionality in .net core so that I can 
displayed saved cards to the user.

Comment: Can you add some context to your question that may help understanding how to best help? What do you mean by "later it throws an error", as in what are you performing later that results in an error? What is the full error?

Comment: Hi @David later means after the second transaction.

Comment: Hi @David thanks for a response the issue is solved.